# Drawing lines relative to content positioned via autolayout

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

Basically, I'd like to draw a line underneath a subview of my UIView, but all of my components are laid out with autolayout.  This means that when drawRect is called and I try to figure out where the bottom of my subview is, I get 0's everywhere because autolayout hasn't kicked in yet.

How should I achieve this?